# imap_open showing 500 Internal Server Error in php

Tags: php, imap, email

I am using the following script to access my email from php.

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to your email account: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Its working in windows server perfectly.

But in linux server it showing following error

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error".

Any one have solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot _guess_ what is happening within your server. Only _you_ can look into it. So what do you see in the http servers error log file? That should _always_ be the first thing you do if you encounter an error in the execution of a php script inside an http server.

Comment: Or is that error string you posted the error message the imap server returns?

Comment: Nothing happening in error log

Comment: Hi arkascha, error log showing.. "GET /test/readMail HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"

Comment: No, that is your http servers access log, not the error log. They are separate. The access log shows the request and the result (indeed 500), the error log shows what happens before.